# Running integration tests throws unsupported operation exception in grails 2.2

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.2 for development. I am running integration tests with test-app -integration command.

I have lots of integration tests but the display shows only a few tests are being run and i get few initialization error exceptions in console. What is the reason for this same error being thrown every now and then?

```
|Running 68 integration tests... 8 of 50
--Output from testGetNumbersAfterInRange--

|Running 68 integration tests... 9 of 50
--Output from initializationError--
Failure: |
initializationError(BillingServiceTests)
|
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1075)


java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1075)


|Running 68 integration tests... 10 of 50
--Output from initializationError--
Failure: |
initializationError(CompositeEventControllerTests)
|
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1075)


java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1075)


|Running 68 integration tests... 11 of 50
--Output from initializationError--
Failure: |
initializationError(CompositeEventControllerTransactionalTests)
|
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1075)


java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1075)
```

Comment: Bug in the tests? Do they work in the command line?

Comment: the shown bug is in Collections class so i doubt it is test case related. Also before intellij i used eclipse ggts and it worked fine. I.e it showed all integration tests and also didnt show this error. The interesting thing here is it is showing initializationerror for all cases.

Comment: Try running in the command line and see what it prints.

Comment: ok i just tried in the command prompt and it shows the same output. i.e it doesnt show the correct amount of tests and shows the same initializationerror.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to just comment so hopefully this is helpful.

First, are they JUnit tests or Spock tests? I think there are issues when they don't end in "Spec" which causes initialization errors if they are meant to be spock tests but do not end in "Spec".

Second, have you tried just running one test, e.g. grails test-app -integration BillingServiceTests. I would turn on verbose and/or debugging on the grails framework; either there is a framework bug or in your test or bootstrap (or some plugin code perhaps) you are trying to add to an unmodifiable Collection.

Comment: thanks i ran one controller test and it showed 1 error failed with the same above error i.e UnsupportedOperationException. Do you think the app is somehow expecting spock tests? i am currently just using unit test or extending GroovyTestCase. plz let me know. Thanks!